# System of linear ODEs

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Determine all solutions for $$X'=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
 2&2  &-1 \\0 
 &1  &0 
\end{pmatrix}X$$

I've calculated $$-(\lambda-1)^3\Rightarrow \lambda=1\\
Eigenvector\ K=
 \begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm not sure of the answer, as the eigenvalue is three times.

Shall the answer be A or B?

$$A:X=c\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}e^t$$

$$B:X=c_{1}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}e^t+c_{2}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}e^t+c_{3}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}e^t$$

EDIT:
$$
(\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
 2&2  &-1 \\0 
 &1  &0 
\end{pmatrix}-2I)P=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow P=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\-1 
\\-1 
\end{pmatrix}\\
(\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
 2&2  &-1 \\0 
 &1  &0 
\end{pmatrix}-2I)Q=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\-1 
\\-1 
\end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow Q=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}\\
X=c_{1}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}e^t+c_{2}(\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}te^t+\begin{pmatrix}
0\\-1 
\\-1 
\end{pmatrix}e^t)+
c_{3}(\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}\frac{t^2}{2}e^t+\begin{pmatrix}
0\\-1 
\\-1 
\end{pmatrix}te^t+\begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 
\\1 
\end{pmatrix}e^t)$$

Did i understood it correct?

Comment: Look at your textbook. Here the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvector is $>1$. What happens in that case?

Comment: Note that your answers $A$ and $B$ are the same, as $c = c_{1} + c_{2} + c_{3}$.

Comment: Compute the Jordan decomposition.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm will check my textbook and update my post.